# How to call a jdialog from a jinternalframe

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jinternalframe

I have an internalframe, i want to create an evenet

```
 private void errorTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

    PaneDialog dlg = new PaneDialog(**this**,true);
  }
```

now the PaneDialog is an JDialog, i cant put the constructor "this" cus "this" is InternalFrame so Netbeans shows an error incompatible types, PaneDiaglog can not be converted to Frame, how i call the JDialog in internalframe?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use one of the `JOptionPane.showInternal???(...)` methods since they only need a Component to be specified as the parent.

Or if you want to get the JFrame for the current internal frame then you can use:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...);
```

and then cast the window to a JFrame.